# AWS CloudWatch no invoca mi lambda

Tags: aws, lambda, ec2, amazon-rds

Hace unos días toque mi cloudwatch y de repente dejó de funcionar.

He probado a crear de nuevo cloudwatch rules y los lambda, pero sigue sin funcionar.

He probado de todo, pero nada lo soluciona.

Cuando pruebas con lambda este funciona correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe alguna solución?

Gracias,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.

Comment: has revisado los permisos IAM?

Comment: @eferion He seguido los pasos de esta página : https://www.totalcloud.io/blog/how-to-schedule-rds-instances-with-an-aws-lambda-function para configurar todo

Comment: Para que cloudwatch pueda ejecutar una lambda necesita estar asociado a un rol IAM que lo permita... yo empezaría por revisar el rol que estás usando actualmente

Comment: @eferion Adjunto imagen del rol que utilizo.

Comment: Fijate que para lambda solo tienes permiso de lectura... con eso podrías, por ejemplo, listar las lambdas creadas... necesitas el permiso de escritura que permite ejecuta lambdas, es decir `lambda:InvokeFunction`

Comment: Si esto soluciona tu problema, avisa y escribo la respuesta para que quede debidamente documentado

Comment: @eferion Sigue sin funcionarme.

Comment: @eferion ¿Se te ocurre alguna otra solución?

Comment: ignoro cómo tienes todo configurado. Te sugiero seguir el [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) de aws

Comment: @eferion Parece que ya me funciona. Lo único que se ejecuta dos horas más tarde de la que debería.